# jQuery Transit issue wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, transition, jquery-transit

I'm implementing a wordpress plugin and i'm getting this error.

Error message:

> "LayerSlider WP: jQuery Transit issue  It looks like one of your other
>   plugins also uses jQuery Transit and loads an extra copy of this
>   library which can cause issues. Please navigate on your WordPress
>   admin area to edit this slider and enable the "Put JS includes to
>   body" option in your Global Settings under the Troubleshooting
>   section."

I have tried to include the .js in the body by enable it from the admin area. But no luck.

I' not sure where to start debugging, and would appreciate any guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have another slider installed as well? Such as revslider? If so uninstall this.

Your LayerSlider should work after, if it doesn't deactivate, rename the plugin within the plugin folder this can be found:

/wp-content/plugins/revslider

If you do not have a slider like this installed, deactivate all plugins and then activate the Layerslider, then systematically turn on plugins until the slider breaks. The cause is a problem with a jQuery conflict on the page, I believe it calls in an older version that layerslider does not like.

Hope this helps.